# Print map with own layer

Tags: google-maps, printing, openlayers, layer, openstreetmap

Given a big city (square is about *800 km^2*) with some layer over it. This layer may contain *multicolor features* such as:

- lines
- points
- text

Number of features is about 1000.

Map resource - *Google Maps* or *Openstreetmap* (or maybe something else?).

My aim is to print such map on a paper with size (about) 5x5 meters. Also this document has to be *high-resolution* - on this paper I want to see buildings with their numbers, streets with captions and so on.

What is the best way to generate such *printable file* (image, document, etc)?

---

Here are some possible solutions that I found:

- I know OpenLayers API so I can draw the layer over Google Maps or Openstreetmap. But how to convert it to printable format?
- I find out that there's [export feature](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Export) on Openstreetmap. But using this feature I can't export my own layer and also it won't be high-resolution.
- Google Maps has [similar feature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?). Using it I can create own layer. But if I have 1000 features than URL will be very big, so server won't load it. Also this map won't be high-resoultion.

---

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the number of pixels / centimeter on your printer?

Comment: This is actually not printer - it's plotter. Unfortunatelly I don't know such techical details. It's just can print paper with size (about) 5mx5m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you set on using the slippy map tiles? If not, you could use something more heavyweight such as a GIS (Geographic information system) package. A good open-source map viewer/manipulator with high-res print capability is [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) but there are others around.

For these you can [import the vector data](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Using_OpenStreetMap_data) (available through OSM export) representing the map, and style it exactly as you would like. There are then several options to export for high-res printing.

Ultimately, you may be asking this question in the wrong place though. Are you aware of: [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Your answer seems to be the best for me. That's why you get bounty and accepted answer. Congratulations! :)

Comment: @Astor. Thank you. You'll probably find the initial startup of getting QGIS to produce pretty output quite a learning curve, but if you're doing stuff with maps more than just once - it'll really pay off. And gis.stackexchange.com is pretty busy and helpful for a relatively niche area.

Answer (score 5):

You want to produce a drawing that's 5 meters by 5 meters of a city that's 40 kilometers by 40 kilometers.  That's a scale of 1 / 8000.

Looking at the Open Street Map tile sets, tile set 17 has a scale of 1 1/2 centimeter to 100 meters, or 150 centimeters to 10,000 meters.  That's a scale of 1 / 6666, which is as close as you're going to get to your desired scale using an Open Street Map tile set.

I've attached an image using that scale.  I'm not sure you're going to be able to see what you want to see.

[image: Open Street Map Level 17]

Anyway, to produce the image you want, you're going to have to do the following in whatever programming language you choose.

- Gather the tiles you need from the Open Street Map web site.  This may take a while, as you will be gathering lots of tiles and they have a limit on the number you can get at a time.
- Stitch the tiles together to form one or more larger images.
- Create your own transparent data layer.
- Superimpose the transparent data layer on the tile layer.
- Print the combined layer image.

Comment: Yes, idea is right, but how to implement it? For example, how to gather tiles and stitch them?

Comment: @Astor: I would use Java, since that's the computer language I'm most familiar with.  You have to write your own computer code to do what you want.  There is no open source off the shelf solution.  I suppose you can use Photoshop to create the transparent data layer.

Comment: Anyway I don't want to create new API for that - this is very complicated. And also my budget is very limited, so I can't buy and learn Photoshop for that. But anyway thanks for your answer (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this grabber](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23865/Map-Grabber-on-C) would help. It just make screenshots from some screen area, then drag the map (by emulating mouse moves), makes another screenshot etc. Then it stitches the screenshots into a single picture. Hence, it can grab virtually any slippy map, that can be opened in browser and be moved by a mouse (without using API - clear WYSIWYG).

Comment: Thanks for answer. C#, windows - don't like them both. Anyway, I will have map image and how will I put features on it? Using image editor?

Comment: As you said, you can make a simple web-app with a slippy map using OpenLayers (LeafLet also a good one) and combine OSM (or Google etc) map with your features. And then grab it. If you need to do this only once, that will do. More 'professional' way is to use GIS as it's suggested below. Using GIS software you can visualize map and features from raw vector data, or use large raster image combined with your layers. Raster image must have geo references though. If you're not familiar with GIS it will take some time to learn.